# Angular: Cors Error when sending data to elasticsearch

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey I have following service and I want to post the data to elasticsearch. However I get the error that the CORS policy blocked the action. I tried to use a proxy script however I still get the error. Can someone help here?

That's the proxy file:

```
{
  "/rest/elastic/*": {
    "target": "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

That' the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HandleError, HttpErrorHandler} from '../http-error-handler.service';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

const userID = '5eada3f00952b44e417fcf82';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostServiceService {

  postElasticUrl = 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/post/_doc';


  private handleError: HandleError;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('TimelineService');
  }

  /** POST Moods to the server */
  postMoods(emoji, text) {

    this.http.post<any>(this.postElasticUrl, '{"emoji":"' + emoji + '","text":"' + text + '","userID":"' + userID
      + '","timestamp":"' + Date.now() + '" }', httpOptions).subscribe();
  }
}
```

And I run the project with

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

The request body looks like that:

```
{emoji: "confused", 
text: "dsv", 
userID: "5eada3f00952b44e417fcf82", 
timeStamp: 1590233638000}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable cors on elastic search server to accept request from ui.

this might help :- http://teknosrc.com/enable-cors-send-cross-domain-request-elasticsearch-ajax-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-http-localhost-9200-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-present-requested-resource/

Just one thing, don't set origin as * use exact origin of your ui.

You are sending a string in post, you should be sending a json. do it like below :-

```
let req = {
   emoji,
   text,
   userId,
   timeStamp: Date.now(),
}
this.http.post<any>(this.postElasticUrl, req, httpOptions).subscribe();
```

Comment: Ok thanks I tried it I don't get the CORS error anymore however now I get a 400 bad request when I am doing a post request

Comment: updated answer above for your 400. so that you can vote if it fix your problem.

Comment: can you show me your requestbody that is going to elasticsearch server?

Comment: bad request means the json you are sending to elasticsearch server is wrong.

Comment: this question was for cors error? Can you please vote for my answer if that fixed your cors issue?

Comment: Ok I did it and I updated the question so that you can see how the request looks right now

Comment: Try same request using postman. I believe your elastic search server is expecting other kind of requestbody.

Comment: Ok I see the problem with the let is that it's not recognised as JSON

Comment: try changing your url to :- 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/post/ui/_doc';   And refer this link for auotmatic creation of indices :- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation

Comment: no http client automatically converts ur object to json. don't change that.

Comment: I just created a new index pattern and then it worked. Thanks for your help